# Copy one element from a vector to another vector

Tags: c++, vector, copy

Hi I would like to know how to copy one element chosen from one vector to another. So for example I have two vectors. I would want to copy the number 7 from v1 to v2 using the position of the element. How can that be done? The code below moves all the elements. What has to b changed?

```
int main() {
   vector<int> v1{ 7,6,5,4,3};
   vector<int> v2;

   copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), back_inserter(v2));

   cout << "v1 vector elements are : ";
   for (int i=0; i<v1.size(); i++)
   {
      cout << v1[i] << " ";
      cout << endl;
   }  

   cout << "v2 vector elements are : ";
   for (int i=0; i<v2.size(); i++)
   {
      cout << v2[i] << " ";
      cout<< endl;
   }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `v2.push_back (v1 [0])` (for your example).

Comment: @PaulSanders Cheers mate, the answer was right in front of me, I didn't trust my initiative

Answer (score 1):

```
v2.push_back(v1[i]);
```

will add the `i`-th element of `v1` to `v2`.

Use `std::copy` when you want to copy a *range* of elements.